# plot specific probability in matplotlib hist

Tags: matplotlib, histogram

Say I have 250 values that show cloud heights from 0 km to 10 km. These values are divided in three categories: category 1 contains 40 values, category 2 contains 120 values, and category 3 contains 90 values. Thus I plot three histograms with bins = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], where the y-axis show the frequency of the values, i.e. in the bin "3" in category 1 there are 10 values.
And here is my problem, I don't want the y-axis to show the frequency, but the probability according to the total value number 250. I hope probability is the right word here... actually I don't want the histogram show, that in category 1 there are 10 values in bin "3", I want it to show that there are 10/250, so 4% of all values in bin "3".

I hope you understand my problem and that you can help me. I can't show parts of my code right now, because I don't have it with me...hope you can help me anyway. Thanx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the histogram function of Numpy and normalize the data yourself by dividing the histogram by the total population of all three categories. The result can be plotted with matplotlib.bar().

I dont think there is a direct way of plotting the histogram. If you pass normed=True to matplotlibs histogram function the weights are normalized to equal 1 so that cant be used to pass a 'relative weight' of the overall histogram.

```
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def myfunc(x, pos=0):
    return '%1.1f%%' % (x*100)

cat1 = np.random.randint(0,11,40)
cat2 = np.random.randint(0,11,120)
cat3 = np.random.randint(0,11,90)

totalpop = float(cat1.size + cat2.size + cat3.size)


fig, axs = plt.subplots(3,1,figsize=(10,9))
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=.3)

for n, cat in enumerate([cat1,cat2,cat3]):

    hist, bins = np.histogram(cat, bins=11, range=(0,11))
    axs[n].bar(bins[:-1], hist/ totalpop, align='center', facecolor='grey', alpha=0.5)
    axs[n].set_title('Category %i' % n)

    print 'Category %i:' % n, 'size: %i' % cat.size, 'relative size: %1.2f' % (cat.size / float(totalpop))


for ax in axs:
    ax.set_xticks(range(11))
    ax.set_xlim(-1,11)
    ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FuncFormatter(myfunc))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I already knew that, but as far as I know the normed argument is only normed to the total number of the specific histogram, but I want it to be normed to the total number of all three histograms, i.e. all three categories. So I could norm the first histogram for category 1, but than it would be normed to the total number of 40 values, but the overall total number is 250 and that's what I want it to be normed to.

Comment: No problem, maybe I didn't explain it right ;-). But thank you very much for you're answer, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Now I have another problem. Because I also want to plot vertical lines to the bar plot...if I do this with "vlines" then I get my vertical lines, but then the bars are not visible anymore. do you know how I can plot a vertical line in the bar plot, say at x=2.4 ?

Comment: vlines works for me. But maybe your max y-value is so large that the bars get squeezed to the bottom axis. Try setting the min and max y-values from the min and max yticks for example, if that works you might find a better way of setting the max x and y value (or a 'hard' set_xlim() on the axes). This works for me, if you set it after plotting the histogram: axs[0].vlines(2.4, np.min(axs[0].get_yticks()), np.max(axs[0].get_yticks()))

Comment: Thanks! Now it works, I think it really was the setting of the max value.